# query to find all the elements in array in mongoose dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongoose

query to find all the elements in the array in mongoose dynamically 
below is the object

```
var res1= {
    "category":["travel","cafe"],
    "amount":"300"
}
```

There could be more elements in the category but I want to create the query which automatically finds all the elements in the database just like forEach works

Comment: So you want to get all of the categories on all of the docs in a collection correct? Looks like you'll need the aggregation pipeline for this. Could you share the schema?

Comment: Hi, Please find the below Schema var DetailSchema = new Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        unique:true
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        enum:["automobile","cafe","grocery","electricity","travel"],
        required:true
    },
    amount:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    total:{
        type:Number
    }

Comment: Okay that clears it up. Never mind what I said about aggregation, see my answer using the ```$in``` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$in` operator should to the trick. `$in` will look for documents where the provided field matches any of the values in the array. the query would look like this:

```
   Detail.find({ 
     category: { $in: ["travel", "cafe"] },
     amount: 300
  })
```

assuming the filters are coming in dynamically on the request, and that `req.body.categories` is an array of desired categories:

```
   Detail.find({ 
     category: { $in: req.body.categories },
     amount: req.body.amount
  })
```